# Android /java echonest file upload errorrr

Tags: java, android, audio-fingerprinting

So i had been trying to figure out how to upload the file on echonest servers for analysis but i am unable to,actually nothing happens after :Track track  = echoNest.uploadTrack(file,true);

```
String[] args={"/storage/sdcard1/Music/Drive soundtrack/A Real Hero (feat. Electric Youth).mp3"};
            File file = new File(args[0]);

            if(!file.canRead())
            {
                printUsage();
                System.out.println("Insert a valid path!");
            }

            System.out.println("validd path!");
            EchoNestAPI echoNest = new EchoNestAPI("080NXJV4Y....");
            System.out.println("hello!");
            Track track  = echoNest.uploadTrack(file,true);

            System.out.println("uploaded!");
            track.waitForAnalysis((60*1000)/2);


            System.out.println("ID: "+track.getID());
            System.out.println("Artist: "+track.getArtistName());
            System.out.println("Title: "+track.getTitle());
```

I came across similar problems while searching over the internet but i couldn't come across a solution.

http://archive-com.com/page/3694036/2014-02-11/http://developer.echonest.com/forums/thread/365

http://developer1072.rssing.com/chan-22893681/all_p31.html#item617

http://developer.echonest.com/forums/thread/1624

here is the error I am receiving

```
08-17 02:27:28.555: I/System.out(2776): EchoNestAPI Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "developer.echonest.com": No address associated with hostname cmd: http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/profile?md5=2fff2dc89742ea6aadf89a96590a2174&api_key=080NXJV4YHVLIVBFA
08-17 02:27:28.555: I/System.out(2776): EchoNestAPI retry failure  cmd: http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/profile?md5=2fff2dc89742ea6aadf89a96590a2174&api_key=080NXJV4YHVLIVBFA
```

Comment: What is appearing on your LogCat? Are you getting any error?

Comment: no there are no erros,it just stops executing

Comment: "hello !" appears and after that nothing appears

Comment: What echonest jar are you using?

Comment: i tired 2 jar's actually

Comment: but right now i am using this 
http://static.echonest.com.s3.amazonaws.com/jEN/files/jEN-latest.zip

the 2 jar's have different syntax for the upload method...
one requires only one parameter i.e only the file

Comment: but the other requires 2 parameters i.e one file and the other a boolean value ]

Comment: Why aren't you surrounding your call with a try catch?

Comment: i am actually,but isn't that a different issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59458/discussion-between-ankit-srivastava-and-joao2fast4u).

Comment: i sent a message on the chat

Comment: and now i did receive an error ...i changed the file into a smaller one and i got an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your api key was invalid and your jar imports were conflicting with each other. You have to make sure you are making that call inside an `AsyncTask`. After that, all is going to work ok.